Azure Blob Storage Put Blob from URL from Salesforce Apex : Error: OutOfRangeInput
I'm attempting to put blobs into Azure Blob Storage from Salesforce that are over 12MB.
I am using Put Blob from URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob-from-url and i have it working with public images but cannot get it to work with salesforce 'public' links to content documents.
I have tried the DistributionPublicUrl and the contentdownloadurl from content distribution but i am getting a Out Of Range error from azure.
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.
Currently using PUT Blob: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob from a remote server to bypass apex limits is not an option.
I'm getting the below error,
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>OutOfRangeInput</Code>
    <Message>One of the request inputs is out of range.
RequestId:749fb49e-101e-001b-6247-a2d651000000
Time:2024-05-09T19:29:08.9534310Z</Message>
</Error>


Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.
